# Respuesta 302 en petición REST con express.js

Tags: nodejs, http, express

Tengo un sistema desarrollado en Node.js con el framework Express y me está pasando algo extraño con las URLs del servicio REST.

Por ejemplo, teníamos la URL de usuarios:

```
GET: /usuario
```

Con el método GET nos devolvía el listado de usuario, pero hace unos días nos comenzó a enviar el error `302`. Estuve investigando y se refiere a un redireccionamiento temporal, si realizo la petición de esta forma

```
GET: /usuario/
```

Con la diagonal al final, sí me responde con `200`, pero lo más raro que antes si funcionaba y todos las URLs de mis servicios los utilizo sin la diagonal al final y están funcionando bien.

La solución más rápida que hice es cambiar la nombre de la ruta por otra. Ejemplo:

```
GET:/usuarios
```

Pero esta no es la solución correcta, ya que hace unos días otra URL nos comenzó a fallar, que es la URL de proyectos:

```
GET: /proyectos
```

El servicio API REST es consumido por un cliente Angular.

Estoy usando el paquete `cors` para el crossdomain:

```
//importacion
var cors = require('cors');
//aplicando para todas las peticiones
app.use(cors());
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar averiguar a qué se debe esta falla.

Comment: Intenté reproducir tu problema y me funciona perfectamente. Estoy usando angular e instale el módulo cors en el server y siempre responde código `200`. Intenté con `GET` y `POST`, con el slash y sin él. Creo que debes incluir parte de tu aplicación tanto en el server como el cliente para ver que es lo que puede estar funcionando mal.

Comment: Gracias @devconcept por su respuesta, como comento en mi publicación la url /usuario y /usurio/ me respondia correctamente, de forma inesperada comenzo a marcarme el código 302 haciendo la petición a la ruta /usuario, y todas las rutas lo consumo con Angular sin la diagonal al final, actualmente el sistema ya cuenta cerca de 70 rutas servicio REST. Lo mas extraño que las otras si funcionan.

Comment: Ok entonces mi intuición me dice que fue algún modulo o configuración que cambiaste recientemente y que posiblemente esté modificando tus rutas. Teoricamente el 302 no es un error sino un estado que debe ser manejado por el cliente. Usualmente el framework manda un `header` de tipo Location que hace que el navegador se encarge del trabajo de redirección. Creo que es mejor que busques que fué lo que provocó el súbito cambio de comportamiento. Encontrarlo te acortará el camino para tener una solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

El framework Express por defecto no enruta estrictamente las URLs como puede verse por la existencia del [parametro de configuracion `strict routing`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set). Sin ver tu codigo no es posible determinar si es este el problema pero deberias asegurarte de que tu aplicacion establece esta configuracion a `true`.